# Where are the Cross Sectional Effect Rows?

Tags: sas

According to the Ajmani textbook and the SAS code book, this is what I should be seeing when using the fixone option:

[image: Cross Sectional Effect Rows]

This is what I am seeing:

[image: No Cross Sectional Effect Rows]

How do I get the cross sectional effect rows? Here is the code I am running:

```
libname mydata "/courses/u_northwestern.edu1/i_1055211/c_6538"
      access=readonly;

/*  Create temporary data sets to mess with */
Data week4;
      set mydata.airlines_week_4;
      Ln_C=log(C);
      Ln_Q=Log(Q);
      Ln_PF=Log(PF);
      label
            C='Total cost ($K)'
            I='Firm Number (CSID)'
            LF='Load Factor (utilization index)'
            Ln_C='Log transformation of costs'
            Ln_PF='Log transformation of fuel price'
            Ln_Q='Log transformation of quantity'
            PF='Fuel price'
            Q='Output in revenue passenger miles (index)'
            T='Time period (TSID)';
run;

/*  This is the program given on the top of page 118 and produces Output 7.4 */
proc panel data=week4;
      id i t;
      Output_7: model Ln_C=Ln_Q Ln_PF LF/fixone;
      title 'OUTPUT 7.4. LSDV estimates for the airlines data using Proc panel.';
run;
```

Where are the cross sectional rows? I don't see any cross sectional effect rows in any output that is supposed to have them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default printing behavior of PROC PANEL for cross sectional effects changed since SAS 9.3TS1M2. The default in SAS9.3TS1M2 is not to print the cross sectional fixed effects while in prior releases the default is printing the cross sectional effects. If you want to include the cross sectional effects in the output in SAS9.3TS1M2 or higher, then you can use PRINTFIXED option on the MODEL statement.